# Take Min key with same values in Dict

Tags: python

I have a dict

```
x={1:1,2:2,3:8,4:8,5:2,6:7,7:4,8:9,10:2}
```

I want to define a function `f(i)` that returns the key having the value `i`.

Now that multiple keys have the same values, the min key should be returned.

Ex-
`i=2`
then in x, 2,5 and 10 has value `i=2`

So 2 must be returned.

```
i=8
```

3 and 4 have value 8 then 3 must be returned.

Is it possible to do this without using loops, as this function act as a base function and will be called from other function multiple times ( approx up to 10^18 )? I want to write this function without a loop. Is it possible?

Comment: It is best to include code attempts that you have tried and then ask specific questions about that code. Otherwise it seems like you haven't attempted to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `min` and dict comprehnesion

```
def find(i):
    return min({k:v for k,v in x.items() if v == i}.keys())
print(find(2))
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: Glad to hear!. if this has helped please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be

```py
def f(dictionary, target_value):
    return min(filter(lambda k: dictionary[k] == target_value, dictionary.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it without directly using loops, is to use the `filter()` function along with the `min()`:

```
x={1:1,2:2,3:8,4:8,5:2,6:7,7:4,8:9,10:2}

def f(i):
    global x
    return min(filter(lambda k: x[k] == i, x))
```

**NOTE:** Although I use `global` to be able to use `x` inside `f()`, it is better to add one more argument in `f()` to avoid globals:

```
def f(x, i):
    return min(filter(lambda k: x[k] == i, x))
```

Testing it with the examples you provided in your question:

```
print(f(2))
print(f(8))
```

will return:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely work fine in your case try the below solution

```
def findMinIndexElement(to_find):
    values = list(x.values())
    keys = list(x.keys())
    try:
        return keys[values.index(to_find)]
    except:
        return 'Not Found'
        

x={1:1,2:2,3:8,4:8,5:2,6:7,7:4,8:9,10:2, 11:7}
to_find = int(input())
print(findMinIndexElement(to_find))
```

Comment: I don't think this does exactly what the OP wants. Try to find the `min` key that has a value of `8` here: `x={1:1,2:2,15:8,4:8,16:8,5:2,6:7,7:4,8:9,10:2}`.